# Formatting Imagemapster selections

Tags: javascript, imagemapster

Hello I'm working on this imagemapster show selection code. People will click on map areas to select.

```
    <div id="veg_demo" style="width:800px; margin: auto;">
        <div style="clear:both;">
        <img id="fvip" width="100%" src="linkto/images/fvip_map.jpg" usemap="#fvip" >
    </div>
        <div style="clear:both; height:8px;"></div>
        <div id="selections" style="clear:both;"></div>
        <a id="show_selected" style="clear:both;">Show Selected Beds:</a>
        <div id="selected" style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>

<map id="fvip_map" name="fvip">
    <area shape="poly" name="915" coords="756,100,756,135,772,135,772,100" href="#" />
    <area shape="poly" name="914" coords="739,100,739,135,755,135,755,100" href="#" />
    <area shape="poly" name="913" coords="717,101,717,136,733,136,733,101" href="#" />
</map>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var image = $('#fvip');
   var xref = {
       <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                $the_query->the_post();
                echo "'$post->ID':\"<h3>Bed number $post->ID</h3>\",";
                    }
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                } else {
                } ?>
   };
   var defaultDipTooltip = 'some text';

   image.mapster(
   {
        render_highlight: {
            fillColor: '2aff00',
            stroke: true,
        },
        render_select: {
            fillColor: '1433d3',
            stroke: true,
        },          
        fillOpacity: 0.8,
        fillColor: "14b842",
        strokeColor: "FFFFFF",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWidth: 4,
        stroke: true,
        scaleMap: false,
        isSelectable: true,
        singleSelect: false,
        showToolTip: true,
        mapKey: 'name',
        listKey: 'name',
        onClick: function (e) {

            var newToolTip = defaultDipTooltip;
            $('#selections').html(xref[e.key]);
            if (e.key==='806') {
                newToolTip = "FVIP";
            }
        },
        showToolTip: true,
        toolTipClose: ["tooltip-click", "area-click", "area-mouseout"],
        areas: [ <?php foreach($posts as $post) { echo "{ toolTip: \"This bed is not available for this date.\", key : \"$post->ID\", isSelectable: false },"; } ?> ]
    });

    function showSelect(){
        $("#show_selected").bind("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#selected').text($("#fvip").mapster("get"));
        });
    }
    showSelect();

  });
</script>
```

but I have no idea on how to make the  selections as a loop, eg:

```
<div>913</div>
<div>914</div>
<div>915</div> ... and so on
```

I would like to style and format each value. Right now the output of the #selected are just 913914915

any help very much appreciated...

thank you

Comment: `.bind` is deprecated, use `.on` - where is your `$('#fvip')
        .mapster()` ?

Comment: Also look into event delegation. https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sb9j7/

Comment: `onClick: function (e) {
    $("#"+e.key).show(); // show the div with ID = key in the mapster
}`

Comment: I have add more code so it will be more clear

Comment: Your showselect is not useful. Change `<div class="bed" id="bed913">This is bed 913</div>` and have  `$(".bed").hide(); $("#"+e.key).show();` in the onclick

Comment: I cannot guess what the `areas: [ <?php foreach($posts as $post) { echo "{ toolTip: \"This bed is not available for this date.\", key : \"$post->ID\", isSelectable: false },"; } ?> ]` do. You cannot run php on the client
`